# Android - (Firebase) Create AutoCompleteTextView with Users Name without knowing usersID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I'm developing a social app that will help people to share their location.**

---

The problem that I'm experiencing is that I want to create an *AutoCompleteTextView with Users Name* which will help User to find other users Profile.However, To be able to do This, I guess we should know UserID to reach *User's name* which is the child of *UserID*

---

This is my Firebase database Structure Image

[image]

The way I tried only help me to autocomplete UserID which is not helpful for me.

---

```
private void initialAutoCompleteTV() {


    SearchPeopleAutoComp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {

            //This is where I do the filtering as the user types

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence.toString())) {
                pullOutTagsSuggestions(charSequence.toString());
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

    });


}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void pullOutTagsSuggestions(final String text) {

    final  ArrayList<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

    Query tagsReferences =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByKey().startAt(text).endAt((text)+ "\uf8ff");
    tagsReferences.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.v("TAGTAGTAG",dataSnapshot.toString());

            if (dataSnapshot != null) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name = (String) ds.getKey();
                    suggestions.add(name);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, suggestions);
                SearchPeopleAutoComp.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Please help me to solve the problem, thanks in advance...

Comment: So you want the uid of the user that is logged in? Is this correct?

Comment: Nope, as I've written there, I want to autocomplete the name of written username in AutoCompleteTextView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onTextChnaged()` get the character the user is typing in realtime by using a method called `subSequence()`. Like this:

```
private void initialAutoCompleteTV() {


    SearchPeopleAutoComp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {

            //This is where I do the filtering as the user types


            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence.subSequence(0, charSequence.length()).toString())) {
                pullOutTagsSuggestions(charSequence.subSequence(0, charSequence.length()));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

    });


}
```

Now what this code is doing is that its simply tracking what the user typing character by character and querying the database at the same time.Hope it help.

**Edit**: I have modified my initial answer to implement the solution in your code. Replace your method `initialAutoCompleteTV()` with the above codes.

Comment: I want to know this query there, how can I create this query... @DevMike

Comment: I have implemented the solution for you, all you need to do is to delete your `initialAutoCompleteTV(){...}` method and replace it with the above code